# Extender MainActivity de AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

buen día, me encuentro realizando un ejercicio de sincronización de datos de esta pagina https://www.develou.com/como-sincronizar-sqlite-con-mysql-en-android/ , me encuentro en el paso 25, pero no sé como puedo reemplazar el extend ya que mi proyecto no lo tiene y el ejemplo es de una versión antigua según entiendo.

Este es el código del ejercicio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

Este es el código de mi ejercicio

```
public class MainActivity  {

}
```

Mi `build.gradle` esta configurado con esta versión

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los proyectos actuales deben usar Android X por lo tanto debes usar el import:

```
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

y tu clase `MainActivity`  extendería de `AppCompatActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```