# actividad con botones con funciones diferentes

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo una actividad con 2 botones y uno funciona y el otro no, tengo que hacerlo con un bucle switch. El primer boton el button info es del boton que manda hacia otra activity para inicar sesion y ese si funciona, y el segundo boton no funciona que quiero que vaya hacia otra activity que es para registrarse.

Aquí os dejo el mainactivity.

```
package com.example.appmensaje10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button info = findViewById(R.id.botoninicio);
       // Button info2 = findViewById(R.id.botonnuevousu);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent intet = new Intent(v.getContext(), actividadregistro.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), actividadiniciosesion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }

        });
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonnuevousu);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), actividadregistro.class);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: te falta el startActivityForResult(intent,0) en el segundo botón.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar... aun asi muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Peli las clases actividadiniciosesion y actividadregistro deben extender de AppCompatActivity para que el intent definido para abrirlas pueda funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he estado probando y me ha funcionado de la siguiente manera.

```
package com.example.appmensaje10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button info = findViewById(R.id.botoninicio);

       info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, actividadiniciosesion.class);
              myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
              v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonnuevousu);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, actividadregistro.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
             v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
           }
       }); 
}
```

En cada Onclick creas un Intent diciendole el primer parametros el Activit actual donde estas, en esta caso seria el MainActivity. Poniendo solamente **this** te funcionaria tambien. Despues con el PutExtra te sirve para pasar parametros a la nueva actividad para poderlos recoger despues eso es opcional, definitivamente coges el context del view y haces startactivity le pasas el intent para que se te ejecute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="98dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="547dp"
        android:text="BIENVENIDO"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botoninicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="324dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="174dp"
        android:text="INICIAR SESION"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botonnuevousu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="326dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="173dp"
        android:text="NUEVO USUARIO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/botoninicio"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero me funciona solo un boton el de iniciar sesion, el de nuevo usuario sigue sin funcionar... de todas formas muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre que tengas algo raro en las actividad que estas llamando, porque debería de irte así.

Comment: te añado el codigo del activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a modificar el código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button info = findViewById(R.id.botoninicio);
    Button nuevoUsuario = findViewById(R.id.botonnuevousu);

    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //puedes hacer el llamado utilizando el nombre de tu actividad: 
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, actividadiniciosesion.class);
            //o utilizando getApplicationContext()
            //Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), actividadiniciosesion.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    
    nuevoUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, actividadregistro.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo una actividad con 2 botones y uno funciona y el otro no,

El problema es que no estas haciendo uso de [startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es-419#startActivity(android.content.Intent)), incluso en este caso el uso de [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es-419#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) no es necesario ya que no esperas una respuesta, revisa :

[Cómo iniciar otra actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419)

Otro punto importante es que las clases `actividadiniciosesion.java` y `actividadregistro.java` [**deben extender de AppCompatActivity**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482576/extender-mainactivity-de-appcompatactivity) y deben estar registradas dentro de `AndroidManifest.xml` .

Este sería el código correcto:

```
info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), actividadiniciosesion.class);                    
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonnuevousu);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), actividadregistro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```